# Java - parent class is calling a method from a child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, parent-child, super

Sorry, I am still new to coding and may not have all the terminologies down. Hopefully, you will still understand my question. The output that I want to get is:

```
"Cost for Parent is: 77.77"
"Cost for Child is: 33.33"
```

However, I am getting this:

```
"Cost for Parent is: 33.33"
"Cost for Child is: 33.33"
```

Can anyone understand why? I have a simplified version of my code below but kept the logic behind it the same...

```
public class Parent{
    public double calculateCost(){
        return 77.77;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Cost for Parent is: " + calculateCost();
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public double calculateCost(){
        return 33.33;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + "\nCost for Child is: " + calculateCost();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Child child1 = new Child();
        System.out.println(child1.toString());
    }
}
```

In my mind, the toString() in the Child class should be calling the toString() from the Parent class (thus, the calculateCost() from Parent class) then adding to it with a calculateCost() from Child. I'm guessing the super in super.toString() does not apply to calculateCost() that it contains.

Also, I know I can get around it by writing the toString() in the Child class like this:

```
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Cost for Parent is: " + super.calculateCost() + "\nCost for Child is: " + calculateCost();
    }
```

but the point is that I don't want to repeat code and that I'd rather add to the previous toString() method that I am overriding. Please help or direct me (not sure what I should be googling for...) Thanks!

Comment: *Also, I know I can get around it by writing the toString() in the Child class like this:* this is the way to do it

Comment: Indeed it is. Sometimes we can't always get what we want.

Comment: What's the point of override?

Comment: The issue is that you've overridden `calculateCost()` in `Child`, so all references to `calculateCost()`in `Parent` now call `Child`'s implementation.  That's how inheritance works.  If `Parent` needs to have a cost of its own that's distinct from that of `Child`, then `Child` shouldn't inherit from `Parent`.  Rather, `Child` should contain a reference to a `Parent` instance.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think the general consensus is that I need to explicitly call the super.calculateCost() in the Child's toString() method in order for it to work since there is no way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`calculateCost` is overriden in the `Child` class. Therefore when `super.toString()` is called from the `Child`, the `calculateCost()` in the `super.toString()` would be the `Child`'s `calculateCost`.

You have to put `super.calculateCost()` explicitly in the `Child` class to call the `Parent`'s `calculateCost`.

Comment: I think I will do it this way. I thought since the toString() in Child should essentially show the same thing as the toString() from Parent but just a little bit more, I was hoping that there would be a way to reuse the toString() from the Parent class in the event where it is not as simple as re-writing a few lines of repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you are calling calculateCost() in toString method. Hence the child's calculateCost() is getting called. You consider using the Child's toString function as below.

```
class Parent{
public double calculateCost(){
    return 77.77;
}

@Override
public String toString(){

    return "Cost for Parent is: " + calculateCost();
}
}

class Child extends Parent{
@Override
public double calculateCost(){
    return 33.33;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Cost for Parent is: " + super.calculateCost() + "\nCost for 
Child is: " + calculateCost();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is upcasting in java.
If subclass and parent class all have a method .then will execute the subclass. If not,then will excute the parent class, although you call the **toString** method including **calculateCost**

method which is in your parent class,but actually **calculateCost** method in the subclass will be exeuted.

You could modify your code as below:

**Parent Class**

```
public class Parent{
    public double calculateCostParent(){
        return 77.77;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "Cost for Parent is: " + calculateCostParent();
    }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    public double calculateCost(){
        return 33.33;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + "\nCost for Child is: " + this.calculateCost();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Child child1 = new Child();
        System.out.println(child1.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Cost for Parent is: 77.77
Cost for Child is: 33.33
```

Then you could avoid the parent and subclasses has the same method of the same name at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can depend on the best match for an overridden method to be called based on the actual type. In this case, you have an instance of a `Child`. Therefore, when you call an overridden method within overridden or non-overridden instance methods, you will see `Child`'s implementation. In other words,

```
Parent p = new Child();
System.out.println(p);
```

would give the same results.

Comment: @almostabeginner, care to elaborate?

Comment: It will print 33.33.

Comment: @almostabeginner, we agree on that actually. I'm saying that the above code will give the same undesirable results, aka 33.33. That's the value of the *actual* (not *apparent*) type in my example.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put a private function prefixed with an underscore in my parent class in those cases to be able to target that specific function and still have the general public overridable function in my parent implementation.

```
public class Parent{
    public double calculateCost(){
        return _calculateCost();
    }

    // Add this parent specific implementation
    private double _calculateCost(){
        return 77.77;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Cost for Parent is: " + _calculateCost();
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public double calculateCost(){
        return 33.33;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return super.toString() + "\nCost for Child is: " + calculateCost();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Child child1 = new Child();
        System.out.println(child1.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this is the behaviour of JVM because in Java whenever we call a method on an object, which belongs to a class that inherits from some other class, the JVM checks whether that method is being overrided or not by the subclass so despite of overriding toString() method from subclass the call to calculate cost() resolves to subclass' version.

Answer (score -1):

I think for this the best thing you could do is use a debug mode so you could better understand how it works. After reading your codes I understand how you want it to run.

But I think there is a problem with how you implement the **@Override Annotation.** The meaning of the

> @Override annotation is to implement a new method that had been
>   literally overriding from the parent class.

In this case, the `public double calculateCost()` of the Parent class will not be used since you Override the calculatecost for the Child class.

I hope I have explained it well. But on this case what you need to do is research more of the @Override and understand how it works.

Comment: `Child`'s `calculateCost()` overrides that of `Parent` simply because it exists, not because of the `@Override` annotation.  `@Override` itself does nothing, it is strictly informative---to both compilers and programmers.

Comment: ohh thank you for that clarification. i've been taught wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Best you can do is to create a parent object, and a child object. Remove super.toString from child's toString method, then you will get the same results:

```
public class Parent{
    double cost = 77.77;
    public double calculateCost(){
        return cost;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Cost for Parent is: " + this.calculateCost();
    }

}

public class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public double calculateCost(){
        return 33.33;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "\nCost for Child is: " + calculateCost();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child child1 = new Child();
        System.out.println(parent.toString() + child1.toString());
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Cost for Parent is: 77.77
Cost for Child is: 33.33
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue; does it? You introduce a new `Parent` instance that isn't in any way related to the `Child` just to get the desired output.